# virtualenvwrapper setup

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I've installed virtualenvwrapper using `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`. However, when I run `source bash_profile` I get this error -`bash: /usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper.sh`: No such file or directory

This is what my `.bash_profile` looks like:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:${PATH}


export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/share/python/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I'm running OSX Mountain Lion and installed python using the instructions provided here https://python-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing an absolute path to `source`, use a dynamic one:

```
source "$(which virtualenvwrapper.sh)"
```